# What are the steps of this command using ; || and &&

Tags: command-line

*Note: A B C are commands.....*

Please tell me what the step process would be of these commands, so I can better understand the language..

```
A || B ; C = If A fails then run B then C?
A ; B || C = Run A then B then C if (B fails... or is it if A fails?)?
```

What I am really after is something like this (but would like to understand the steps above):

If A fails, then run B, but if A succeeds, skip B then run C,d,e,etc (How can I do this with "||" ";" and/or "&&"?)

I found information from this link, but it only shows the steps of 2 commands, not 3.... https://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/which-one-is-better-using-or-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-one-line

Reason why another link does not answer this question:

> > So, next time if you need to chain 4 commands you'll ask a new question because the answers here only show how 3 commands work ?–  don_crissti26 mins ago
> >
> > No sir, because I'll understand the linguistic next step for the future :). Mostly because of this....: I was unclear if the command and switch(?) " || " in sequential order (command C in this case) was always looking at command (A) or if it was looking command (B). This is mostly because I was confused by someone saying this: A || B = Run B if A failed.. wasn't sure if the next command (C, D, etc etc) would look at A as well :) (duh is what it seems, but I don't know this language... so had to get clarity).

Comment: @don_crissti It is very similiar except they only show how 2 commands work.. not 3 :)

Comment: So, next time if you need to chain 4 commands you'll ask a new question because the answers here only show how 3 commands work ?

Comment: No sir, because I'll understand the linguistic next step for the future :). Mostly because of this....: I was unclear if the command and switch(?) " || " in sequential order (command C in this case) was always looking at command (A) or if it was looking command (B). This is mostly because I was confused by someone saying this: A || B = Run B if A failed.. wasn't sure if the next command (C, D, etc etc) would look at A as well :) (duh is what it seems, but I don't know this language... so had to get clarity).

Comment: @R0tten `&&` and `||` are left-associative binary operators with equal precedence. The `;` is not an operator at all but merely a simple separator, like a newline, and as such has the lowest "precedence". That should be enough to clear up any confusions you have.

Answer (score 2):

```
A || B ; C
```

if A exits with a non-zero status, run B. C runs unconditionally

```
A ; B || C
```

run A. Then run B. If B exits with a non-zero status, run C

---

Tangientially, you'll sometimes see `A && B || C`. This is usually intended to be a shorthand for `if A; then B; else C; fi`. However, there is one major difference:

```
A && B || C
```

- If A fails, run C
- if A succeeds, then run B.

  - **if B fails, run C**

```
if A; then B; else C; fi
```

- If A fails, run C
- if A succeeds, then run B.

  - **if B fails, C is NOT executed**

A demo:

```
$ (echo A; exit 0) && (echo B; exit 1) || (echo C; exit 2); echo $?
A
B
C
2     # <== the exit status of C

$ if (echo A; exit 0); then (echo B; exit 1); else (echo C; exit 2); fi; echo $?
A
B
1     # <== the exit status of B
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple test

```
(echo -n "hello" || echo -n "world") && echo "!"
```

produces "hello!"

Alternatively (making statement A false)

```
( false || echo -n "world") && echo "!"
```

produces "world!"

OR operators are lazy, thus if A is true in (A || B), B is never evaluated, as True OR True == True and True OR False == True